# Erase range from a std::vector?

Tags: c++

If my `std::vector` has 100 elements, and I only want to keep the first 10 and erase the rest, is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
vec.resize(10); // drops the rest (capacity remains the same)
```

Comment: This will not work if the element does not have a default constructor.

Answer (score 59):

Yes, there is an [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) function that takes arguments for first and last.

```
v.erase(v.begin() + 10, v.end());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
theVector.erase(theVector.begin() + 10, theVector.begin() + 100);
```

Answer (score 6):

`vec.erase(vec.begin() + 10, vec.begin() + 100);`