# Remove a Chunk of Items from a Vector?

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have a vector full of words and I am trying to erase a chunk of that vector at a specified beginning and end. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words = { "The", "Quick", "Brown", "Fox", "Jumps", "Over", "The", "Lazy", "Dog" };
    words.remove_chunk(1, 2);
}
```

Here, `words.remove_chunk(1, 2);` would erase the items at index 1 through 2, leaving the vector to be:

```
{ "The", "Fox", "Jumps", "Over", "The", "Lazy", "Dog" }
```

How would I go about efficiently writing `remove_chunk`? Is there an stl function for this or a quick one-liner?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333574/erase-range-from-a-stdvector/5333587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vector::erase`:

```cpp
words.erase(words.begin(), words.begin() + 2);
```

Note: Second iterator provided is `words.begin() + 2` instead of `words.begin() + 1` because STL uses [begin, end).